# Why won't HttpPost send any data?

Tags: android, httpclient

I have an old android app that I use for some years. There is a function that does a post request on the server that is run by an Async task.

It worked fine. Now it stopped working. I debugged a lot and realized that the post is getting as null to the server. The server page is working as expected (posts get through when from another origin).

I tried changing headers, sending an json, stringentity, urlencodedentity, nothing works. I have no clue what can be wrong. Also tried using HTTPUrlConnection for the same result.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
    protected String PostByHttpClient(String url, List<NameValuePair> postParams) throws IOException
    {           
        // Com erro depois de uma atualização, setEntity não insere variaveis no post, por algum motivo.
        final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 25000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        String Params = "?"+getQuery(postParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url/*+Params*/);

        // monta o header
        post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        //post.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        //post.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        //post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        post.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        post.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

        // executa submit (post)
        StringEntity entity;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            //entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams, HTTP.UTF_8);
            entity = new StringEntity(getJSONQuery(postParams),HTTP.UTF_8);
            post.setEntity(entity);
            response = client.execute(post);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("SURV", ex.getMessage());
        }

        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        Log.i("Quest", "\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        Log.i("Quest", "Post parameters : " + getJSONQuery(postParams));
        Log.i("Quest", "Response Code : " + responseCode);
        Log.i("Quest", "Method: " + post.getMethod());

        // código de status HTTP (2xx = sucesso)
        if (responseCode >= 300) throw new HttpResponseException(responseCode, response.getStatusLine()
                .getReasonPhrase()+" - "+url);

        // sucesso (lê o retorno da pagina)
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        return result.toString();       
    }
```

`getJsonQuery` converts a NamePairValue to Json (and its working).

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), is quite simple and straightforward.

Comment: It's not a bad suggestion, but the server is not REST, and the app uses that function for many different calls to the server, meaning I would have to create several separate classes and interfaces to use it.

Also, I would like to know why this is not working and how to solve it.